# How can I get smooth transitions on nested sliders using AnythingSlider?

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I'm trying to create nested sliders using AnythingSlider,

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? Do you have some code you could show us? And what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are having trouble, but [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/S8Je5/217/) of a slider nested inside of another one using the latest version of AnythingSlider, [available here](http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider/).